# 10MB Docx file takes more time to convert pdf using docx4j

Tags: java, docx4j

Convert 10MB Docx file takes more time to convert pdf. Sometimes got OOM error. Also is there any options to get first page of doc and convert it into PDF.

```
Following code snippets to convert docx file to pdf

Maven Dependencies:

`<dependency>
            <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>docx4j</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>`
    <br><br><b>Java code to convert docx to pdf:</b> 

`ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                System.out.println("Start : "+new Date());
                WordprocessingMLPackage wordprocessingMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(bis);
                Docx4J.toPDF(wordprocessingMLPackage, bos);
                System.out.println("End : "+new Date());
`
```

Comment: Isn't it natural that larger files take more time? What's your question?

Comment: It will take more time around 5 mins to convert in pdf. Is there any way to take first page of doc and convert into pdf